# Sinon Spy for Non-Class Methods

Tags: javascript, mocking, sinon, stubbing

I have a javascript file with a bunch of util functions in a file called utils.js

```
export const processListOfItems = (input): [] => {
  let listOfItems = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < rawPayload.length; ++index) {
    listOfItems.push(someFunction(item));
  }
  return listOfItems;
};
```

someFunction is defined in utils.js as well.

For the test, I would like to stub "someFunction," but am having trouble figuring out how to do so. It looks like sinon.spy() might be the method I want, but it looks like it requires an object, of which I don't have one since it's just a utils file.

My ideal test would look something like this

```
describe('someFunction fails on an item', () => {
  it('returns the array with the rest of the items', () => {
    const items = ['hi', 'hello'];

    // I want to make it such that, when we go into the getListOfItems code, we return 42 whenever we call someFunction, rather than going into the logic itself.
    const someFunctionStub = sinon.stub(someFunction).returns(42);

    expect(getListOfItems(items)).toEqual([42, 42]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`sinon.stub` replaces a property on an object...

...and often the object is a *module* and the property is *a function the module exports*.

When the *module export* of a function is stubbed, any code that calls the *module export* of the function will then call the stub.

---

It isn't possible to stub `someFunction` in the code above since `processListOfItems` isn't calling the *module export* of `someFunction`, it is calling `someFunction` directly.

`processListOfItems` needs to call the *module export* of `someFunction` in order to be able to stub the call.

---

Here is a simple example to demonstrate using Node.js module syntax:

util.js

```
exports.func1 = () => {
  return 'hello ' + exports.func2();  // <= use the module
}

exports.func2 = () => 'world';
```

util.test.js

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const util = require('./util');

describe('func1', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(util, 'func2').returns('everyone');
    expect(util.func1()).toBe('hello everyone');  // Success!
  });
});
```

---

...and here is a simple example using ES6 module syntax:

util.js

```
import * as util from './util';  // <= import module into itself

export const func1 = () => {
  return 'hello ' + util.func2();  // <= use the module
}

export const func2 = () => 'world';
```

util.test.js

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as util from './util';

describe('func1', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(util, 'func2').returns('everyone');
    expect(util.func1()).toBe('hello everyone');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Note that ES6 modules can be imported into themselves since they ["support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_cyclic-dependencies-in-ecmascript-6).